# How to convert the Images pixel Coordinate into the PDF coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, coordinates

Using the **jQuery draggable library** to set the coordinates on the images and using the **pdf-lib library** to set the coordinates on the pdf.

Here are some coordinate which are set during the drag and drop

```
Image (Width * Height)  => 825px * 1074px
After draggable item (Width * Height)  => 209px * 66px
Coordinate Poistion = (x,y) => 491px*519px
New PDF size = (width * height) = 609 x 791 pts
```

Using 1px = 0.75pts to convert the pixel to points
and getting the new coordinates according to the new width and height
[image]

I don't know with my code since the signature points are not on the right place. Need Help

Comment: Can you show us you code?Are you usig [getBoundingRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the element features?

Comment: Not using the getBoundingReact() using the ui.helper[0] of draggable